# Setting UITableView row selection programmatically returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to call a TableView row to be selected programatically.

All my delegates are set properly, and the `UITableView` is linked in IB. All other `UITableView` methods work properly, and are located in either the main ViewController or its extension.  When the following is called I get `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

```
func selectTableViewRowProgrammatically () {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: someVariable, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)
    tableView.delegate?.tableView!(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Error shows on `self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)`

Thanks!

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error? And why are you attempting to call the delegate method yourself? You should not do that. If you have common code you need to call, put the code in a function. Then call that function from `didSelectRowAt` and `selectTableViewRowProgrammatically`.

Comment: Did you implement `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`? This method is optional, and I see you're force unwrapping it when calling it. This may be the reason of the crash.

Comment: Add code, where you set a delegate to the tableView, may be there a error exist.

Comment: @Julien I am implementing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        someVariable = indexPath.row

    }`.  However I'd like to be able to tap on the cell and set the someVariable as well.  Essentially, if the user taps the TableView row they set the someVariable based on the row, or, if Firebase or another button sets/advances someVariable I'd like that to be reflected in the TableView.  Thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy error shows on `self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition.none)`

Comment: @moosgrn That implies that `tableView` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

can you try Following code

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: someVariable, section: 0)

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                   tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false) 

                }) { (true) in
                    tableView.delegate?.tableView!(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

                }
```